# WPF: Canvas mouse events not firing on empty space

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas

I have set mouse events on a `Canvas` as follows:

```
<Canvas MouseUp="CanvasUp" MouseDown="CanvasDown" MouseMove="CanvasMove">
...
</Canvas>
```

But these are active only on the child elements like `Image` and `Rectangle`, not on the empty space.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

A control with no background color set (explicitly or through styles etc) will default to having a background color of null - making it not hit-testable.

If you set the background to "Transparent" (or anything other than null (`{x:Null}`)) then it will be able to pick up the mouse events

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what a STUPID design decision the WPF team did with that.

Comment: This advice is valuable a golden coin !
I'd rather default Canvas background to Transparent, rather than {x:null} as normally you'd expect event (with appropriate arguments) to fire when you click on canvas empty space.
The default x:null behavior should be optionally settable, rather.

Answer (score 5):

Set the background color.  It defaults to `null`.

Use `Background="White"` for instance.