# Making Things Under Canvas Not Receive Events

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, events

I'm using Visual C# 2015 to develop a WPF project.

I have a `Button` underneath a `Canvas`. I'd like to make the `Canvas` capture all mouse events, so that the `Button` does not receive any of those events as long as the `Canvas` is in front. If possible, I'd also like to prevent the `Button` from receiving any event generated by user input, like `KeyDown` or `MouseMove`.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: off-topic question: why do you have a `Button` underneath a `Canvas`?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just disable the button, when you don't want it to receive input?

Comment: @KevinWallis Because I'd like to render things on top. I'm trying to build a basic GUI editor.

Comment: @Lithium Because if I do, it's rendered differently.

Comment: Could you please post your XAML markup? What does "underneath" mean here?

Comment: @mm8 I'm afraid I can't do this right now. Underneath here means `Panel.ZIndex` is lower.

Comment: Does the Button reside *inside* the Canvas or in the same panel as the Canvas? And why can't you post your markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stop the event propagation, you could use:

```
private void CanvasEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Draw/Move stuff
    ...
    e.Handled = true;   
}
```

in your event handlers. Another approach is to `disable` the `Button` or only add it, when it is used. A third approach could be to add a `bool` flag e.g. `isDrawing` and in your `Button` event handler you check the flag.

```
private void CanvasEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // When drawing etc. starts, where the button should not handle the events
    isDrawing = true;  
}

private void ButtonEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDrawing) { return; }
    // When not drawing do stuff
    ...
}
```

I would prefer the `e.Handled = true;` approach.
It is necessary to set the `Background` for the `Canvas` explicite otherwise it is not hit-testable (see: [WPF: Canvas Events Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507165/wpf-canvas-events-not-working)).

Comment: Unfortunatelly `e.Handled = true` doesn't stop propagation in this scenario and the `isDrawing` approach would still leave the click animation, while disabling the button causes its rendering to be different.

Comment: @MaxRied why does `e.Handled = true` not stop the propagation?

Comment: `button` underneath `canvas`. `button.MouseMove: MessageBox.Show("MouseMove");` `canvas.MouseMove: e.Handled = true;` When I move the cursor, the `MessageBox` appears...

Comment: try to add the `e.Handled = true` to the `canvas PreviewMouseMove` because the `MouseMove` event is when bubbling up used but you need the tunneling event.

Comment: I'm afraid that makes no difference: `button` underneath `canvas`. `button.MouseMove: MessageBox.Show("MouseMove");` `canvas.PreviewMouseMove: e.Handled = true;` When I move the cursor, the `MessageBox` still appears.

Comment: @MaxRied have you explicite set a `Background` for the `Canvas`?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the problem. I changed the background to transparent, now it works!